# Delete row from virtual database

Tags: android

I have a database created like:

```
  mDatabase.execSQL(FTS_TABLE_CREATE);
```

where `FTS_TABLE_CREATE`:

```
   private static final String FTS_TABLE_CREATE =
                "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE +
                        " USING fts3 (" +
                        KEY_WORD + ", " +
                        KEY_DEFINITION + ");";
```

Then I add a new row to it:

```
public long addTitle(String word) {
            ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
            initialValues.put(KEY_WORD, "test");
            initialValues.put(KEY_DEFINITION, "null");

            return getWritableDatabase().insert(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE, null, initialValues);
        }
```

And now I need to delete it:

```
public void removeTitle(String title) {
            getWritableDatabase().delete(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE, KEY_WORD + "=" + title, null);
        }
```

But I got an exception:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: test: , while
>   compiling: DELETE FROM FTStitleslist WHERE suggest_text_1=test

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
getWritableDatabase().delete(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE, KEY_WORD + "=" + title, null);
```

To this (recommended):

```
getWritableDatabase().delete(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE, KEY_WORD + " = ?", new String[]{title});
```

Or this (not recommended):

```
getWritableDatabase().delete(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE, KEY_WORD + "= '" + title + "'", null);
```